# Windows Server crashes unexpectedly , lsass.exe, failed with status code 255

Tags: windows, windows-server

My windows server crashes every few days with this error:

> A critical system process, C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe, failed with
>   status code 255.  The machine must now be restarted.

the forums in MSDN are not very clear regarding how to handle this issue.
I run always a administrator, through RDP.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably a virus. Alot of them acts like this.

Comment: 1) Make a Backup. 2) Check CPU temperature, fan is running? 3) Run a good antivirus, Full Scan.

Comment: I ran a full scan - not a virus. Temperature is fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Which version of Windows Server are you running?

Comment: I think you'll get more attention at either [su] or [sf]. Check their help pages to know where it belongs to; also see [help/on-topic] for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Try WindDBG from Windows Debugging tools from Microsoft. Download the symbols files for you windows version. Then debug step by step-into lsass.exe with remote debugging from an another machine. You always end up to see what's wrong with kernel mixed userland debugging.... (Also, please notify @ me I don't check for answers manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd tried if I were you, in that order:

1. Go to device manager and select your NIC card. Select properties, then power management. De-select "allow computer to turn off this device to save power". Reboot and try to reproduce.
2. [Open this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2732595), check your OS version, check your event log for the event “Source: LsaSrv Event ID: 5000”, if everything matches, install the supplied hotfix. Reboot and try to reproduce.
3. [Same with this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969837) — check OS version, check your event log, apply the hotfix if it fits.
4. Set DefaultEncryptionType registry value [as specified here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f5f44b82-b0cc-4813-8199-62964f386500/lsassexe-failed-with-status-code-255-at-random-times?forum=w7itprogeneral). However please keep in mind that this one is risky, esp. if the server is a DC. Make sure you have a fresh backup, and physical access to the server.

Comment: this is a Windows Server 2012 - so the hot fixes don't apply to him, I guess that was not the issue. but the first section with the device manager looks helpful. thanks :)